# Is it possible to filter the dump in mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

I'm using `mysqldump` and I would like to ignore the data (in other words, fetch just the create table) of some **specific** tables, so the rest of the dump would contain the creates **and** the data.

I'm aware of the existence of the `-d` flag and `--ignore-table`, is there any way to combine them? Or another mechanism?

Comment: You could issue two `mysqldump` commands - one for your tables where you just want the structure, and one for the other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify all the name tables to include manually and use the `--no-data` option. The `--ignore-table` option only applies when table names have *not* been specified, in which the default is to "include all".

However, it is not possible to directly "mix" different modes; run separate dumps and combine/append the results or use a different tool.

For example, consider:

```
mysqldump --no-data mydb table1 table2                      >  dump.sql
mysqldump --ignore-table table1 --ignore-table table2 mydb  >> dump.sql
```